# php only allow access to a certain file?

Tags: php, mod-rewrite

how can i show only the index.php and ignore any other calls to other php files, so if i were to go to somefile.php, the page would stay at index.php all the time, however if i were to go to index.php?get=somefile it would then allow you to execute that.

so in short i only want the index.php to be the main caller and executor of everything and to ignore any calls to any other php files that is not index.php.

i have this in my .htaccess.

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1
```

it does everything i'm asking for but it dosen't let you call any php file using get in index.php like `index.php?get=somefile`

where is it going wrong and how do i correct it?

Comment: So are you saying that if someone goes to index.php?get=somefile you want it to redirect to somefile.php or you want it to remain on index.php but include the contents of somefile.php?

Comment: everything will remain on index.php, and it will include the contents of any called file

Answer (score 0):

You are not rewriting the get parameter. Try this:

```
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?get=$1
```

Answer (score 0):

Right Now your htaccess code is creating a url of:

```
index.php/somefile.php
```

Add

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^index.php.*
```

From here you can do two things

1) Change RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 to:

```
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?get=$1
```

2) Add another RewriteRule:

```
RewriteRule ^index.php/(.*)$ index.php?get=$1 [L]
```

Depending on your server setup you may need to change index.php?get=$1 to one of the following

```
./index.php?get=$1
http://yourdomain.com/index.php?get=$1
```

Then on your index.php page you would include the page passed by the $_GET['get'] variable.

Answer (score 0):

Here's your final rule, tell me if it works:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/?get=$1 [QSA,L]
```

Answer (score -2):

http://wiki.apache.org/httpd/RewriteFlags/QSA

```
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [QSA]
```

So if you went to `site.com/?get=asdf`, you could access that via `$_GET['get']` in your `index.php` file.

Comment: He had stated he wanted site.com/somefile.php to be redirected to index.php?get=somefile.php. With QSA if someone puts somefile.php?var=test. It would become site.com/index.php/somefile.php?var=test but with no other rule the server will return more than likely "Page Not Found"

Comment: OP said "so in short i only want the index.php to be the main caller and executor of everything and to ignore any calls to any other php files that is not index.php."

That rewrite rule would send everything through index.php, and he could use include() or similar to execute $_GET['get'] (after filtering for LFI/RFI).

Comment: OP did say that but your rewrite rule will lead to "Page Not Found" (most of the time) or index.php page with the structure not correct due to improper rule set. Not able to find css/includes/js. I have tried yours that is why I have an additional rule in my answer. I tried it prior to posting.

Comment: You're wrong with `QSA`. `QSA` means: "apply the rule, and then, *once it is applied*, if there was something in the GET of the URL **before applying that rule** then add it to the rewritten URL **once again**". So, if you access the site via `site.com/test/?aa=asdf` and apply `^(.*)$ index.php/$1` then: (1) **without** QSA the final URL will be `index.php/test/` and (2) **with** QSA you'll get `index.php/test/?aa=asdf`

Comment: @JamesWilliams yes, but that's what the two `RewriteCond` lines (which I really should have included in my answer as well) are for. They'll prevent 404s.


@OlivierPons see my previous comment. OP wants index.php to handle everything - `site.com/test/?aa=asdf` will still fire index.php. The `test` portion of the URL can be accessed via `$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']`.